# Discord.NET Slash commands not showing

Tags: c#, discord, permissions, bots, discord.net

So I making a discord Bot and for some Reason I can't see the slash command I created.

**Slash command**

```cs
[SlashCommand("ping", "Receive a ping message")]
public async Task HandlePingCommand()
{
    await RespondAsync("Stop pinging me!");
}
```

I'm almost sure it has something to do with the bots permissions.
I have set the GatewayIntents AllUnprivileged and MessageContent.

**Discord Developer Portal Permissions**
[image]
[image]

[image]

**Added Information**

```cs
if (IsDebug())
    await sCommands.RegisterCommandsToGuildAsync("my server id"));
else
    await sCommands.RegisterCommandsGloballyAsync(true);
```

I also added the applications.commands scope

If any more information and / or code is need I'll ofcourse add it.

Comment: https://discordnet.dev/guides/int_framework/intro.html#registering-commands-to-discord

Comment: @Anu6is I already got the sCommands.RegisterCommands part in my code. But <test_guild_id> is my Server ID right?

Comment: You also have to add the scope "application.commands" in the developer portal

Comment: @BobSty I added the scope (makes sense that you need this) but sadly it still doesn't work

Comment: you have to reinvite the bot to the server so the scope applies I think

Comment: @BobSty I already did that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same issue, this is how I figured it out:

1. enable logging and see if it logs any errors etc (one of my problem was I had a `class` passed into my method of the command which doesn't supported by the API: `No type TypeConverter is defined for this Discord.WebSocket.SocketSlashCommand`)

```cs
_client.Log += message => // this one
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
};
// other code
_client.Ready += OnClientReady;
await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, discordToken);
await _client.StartAsync();
```

2. Try to set `GatewayIntents.All`

```cs
var config = new DiscordSocketConfig
{
    GatewayIntents = GatewayIntents.All
};
```

3. Make sure it's similar to my code

```cs
private async Task OnClientReady()
{
    _client.Ready -= OnClientReady;
    _interactionService = new InteractionService(_client);
    await _interactionService.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), _serviceProvider);
    await _interactionService.RegisterCommandsGloballyAsync();
    _client.InteractionCreated += async interaction =>
    {
        var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        var ctx = new SocketInteractionContext(_client, interaction);
        try
        {
            await _interactionService.ExecuteCommandAsync(ctx, scope.ServiceProvider);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error executing command: {ex.Message}");
        }
    };
}
```

4. Try to open Discord in browser and use your command /yourcommand, after that, my command appeared in both the browser and the Discord app